# No Wireless connection but Ethernet works fine

Tags: networking, intel-wireless

I'm now trying for days to fix the wireless problem I'm recently facing on my laptop but unfortunately I am not able to figure out how it came about, nor how to fix it.

So I hope you guys can help me.

I already did a clean install, without any improvement.
Sometimes, after reboot, I see wireless networks but when I try to connect it fails.

I also tried using the proprietary drivers, again without any change. Currently, the standard Ubuntu drives are installed.

As I read in several other posts, the output of the wireless script might be of use to you, here is what it gives me:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 27 Nov 2016 18:56 CET +0100

Booted last: 27 Nov 2016 00:00 CET +0100

Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-47-generic #68-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 26 19:39:52 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

MATE

##### lspci #############################

00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [17aa:21f3]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 056a:00e6 Wacom Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b44d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 147e:2020 Upek TouchChip Fingerprint Coprocessor (WBF advanced mode)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 17ef:6044 Lenovo 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bdb:1911 Ericsson Business Mobile Networks BV 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: tpacpi_wwan_sw: Wireless WAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

wmi                    20480  0

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr   
          inet addr:192.168.1.233  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5497:bf53:d98a:1a31/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:107 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:147 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:10445 (10.4 KB)  TX bytes:17070 (17.0 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f2400000-f2420000 

wwp0s20u4i6 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr   
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s25   no wireless extensions.

wwp0s20u4i6  no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s25
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s25

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search localdomain

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       703     1  0 18:56 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s25
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         e1000e
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 3.2.6-k
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               0.13-3
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0/net/enp0s25
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp0s25
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       d7384583-b7e5-3227-9265-1e4899d237ec
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{1}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   d7384583-b7e5-3227-9265-1e4899d237ec | Wired connection 1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.233/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          localdomain
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        host_name = stefan-X230T
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       expiry = 1480874175
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       ip_address = 192.168.1.233
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       domain_name = localdomain
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 604800
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::5497:bf53:d98a:1a31/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            
IP6.DNS[1]:                             fe80::1
DHCP6.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp6_client_id = 0:4:d7:48:72:6:25:26:4c:f4:3:e5:c7:38:86:ce:8c:54
DHCP6.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp6_name_servers = fe80::1
DHCP6.OPTION[3]:                        requested_dhcp6_name_servers = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[4]:                        requested_dhcp6_domain_search = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[5]:                        requested_dhcp6_client_id = 1
DHCP6.OPTION[6]:                        dhcp6_domain_search = localdomain.
DHCP6.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp6_preference = 255
DHCP6.OPTION[8]:                        dhcp6_server_id = 0:3:0:1:

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         ttyACM0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           gsm
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceModem
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Lenovo
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        F5521gw
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         cdc_acm, cdc_wdm, cdc_ncm
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/WY-WLAN]] (600 root)
[connection] id=WY-WLAN | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=WY-WLAN
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Berlin (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp0s25   no frequency information.

wwp0s20u4i6  no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp0s25   Interface doesn't support scanning.

wwp0s20u4i6  Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

[/etc/pm/power.d/disable_wol] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/laptop-mode] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/pci_devices] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/pcie_aspm] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/sched-powersave] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/usb_bluetooth] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/wireless] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/xfs_buffer] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[    3.383240] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[    4.026013] cdc_ncm 3-4:1.6 wwan0: register 'cdc_ncm' at usb-0000:00:14.0-4, Mobile Broadband Network Device, 
[    4.028386] cdc_ncm 3-4:1.6 wwp0s20u4i6: renamed from wwan0
[    6.214147] e1000e: enp0s25 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[    6.214314] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s25: link becomes ready
[    6.997739] psmouse serio2: trackpoint: IBM TrackPoint firmware: 0x0e, buttons: 3/3

########## wireless info END ############
```

I appreciate any help, hints, comments....

Thanks, Stefan

### Edit

For easier readability I update my post, such that the made progress due to the comments is also included in my question.
In addition to the above information, it was asked for the output of `lspci -nnk`, which is the following

```
~$ lspci -nnk
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [8086:0154] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [17aa:2203]
    Kernel driver in use: ivb_uncore
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [17aa:2203]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [17aa:2203]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller [17aa:2203]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:16.3 Serial controller [0700]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family KT Controller [8086:1e3d] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family KT Controller [17aa:2203]
    Kernel driver in use: serial
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [17aa:21f3]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller [17aa:2203]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [17aa:2203]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1e10] (rev c4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1e12] (rev c4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:1e14] (rev c4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller [17aa:2203]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation QM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1e55] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo QM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller [17aa:2203]
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:1e03] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [17aa:2203]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1e22] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [17aa:2203]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
02:00.0 System peripheral [0880]: Ricoh Co Ltd PCIe SDXC/MMC Host Controller [1180:e823] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo PCIe SDXC/MMC Host Controller [17aa:2203]
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
    Kernel modules: sdhci_pci
```

Note: in the comments I also gave a link to the output of the above command when the laptop is attached to my docking station. But since this is not directly related to this problem, it should not be considered here.

Comment: Where did you get that script?

Comment: Here you have the drivers for your card https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/15817/Intel-Network-Adapter-Driver-for-PCI-E-Gigabit-Network-Connections-under-Linux-?product=47549

Comment: @M.Becerra That is a driver for his ethernet card, not wireless. His ethernet card already has a working driver.

Comment: We see no wireless device at all. Is it enabled in the BIOS? Is it broken?

Comment: @M.Becerra See for example: http://askubuntu.com/a/425205/624180

Comment: @chili555 I just checked in the BIOS, but I can't find anything related to wireless, normally it should be under config or advanced right? Hmm, if it is broken, the ethernet should have also stopped working, shouldn't it?

Comment: No, the ethernet chip and the wireless card are two completely different devices. Let's dig deeper. Please run: `lspci -nnk` and paste the result here and give us the link. http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: @chili555 Ahh ok, I somehow thought that both are handled by the same device... Anyway.. Here is the output http://paste.ubuntu.com/23571601/. If I run the command when my laptop is connected to the docking station I get http://paste.ubuntu.com/23554223/, the strange thing here, it also have a network controller which uses iwlwifi but wireless does also not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good thing, my wireless connection works again. As one can see from the output below, the network controller is recognized again by my system.

```
$ lspci -nnk
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [8086:0154] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [17aa:2203]
    Kernel driver in use: ivb_uncore
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [17aa:2203]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [17aa:2203]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller [17aa:2203]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:16.3 Serial controller [0700]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family KT Controller [8086:1e3d] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family KT Controller [17aa:2203]
    Kernel driver in use: serial
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [17aa:21f3]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller [17aa:2203]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [17aa:2203]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1e10] (rev c4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1e12] (rev c4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:1e14] (rev c4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller [17aa:2203]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation QM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1e55] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo QM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller [17aa:2203]
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:1e03] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [17aa:2203]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1e22] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [17aa:2203]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
02:00.0 System peripheral [0880]: Ricoh Co Ltd PCIe SDXC/MMC Host Controller [1180:e823] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo PCIe SDXC/MMC Host Controller [17aa:2203]
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
    Kernel modules: sdhci_pci
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [8086:0085] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 AGN [8086:1311]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

The bad thing, I can only guess that some (regular) update fixed the problem since I didn't do anything fancy, but just updated the system as usual.

I know that this is not a satisfying answer, nor a rather helpful one to somebody who experience the same problem, but since for me the problem is fixed I'll consider is at solved and accept my answer.